# Box2d - Get width of fixture from a body or should I even try?

Tags: c++, box2d

I have read some threads about this but they did not really look clear to.
Therefore.. How to find the width of one fixture? I know hot to get access to the fixture and all that but do not really know about the last part. Especially, I do not know how to do this the most efficient way and if you actually would be better off storing a float variable as userData for the body.

Thanks, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this task via 2 methods:

**1)** Attach a shape to the fixture and then use the shape values. No need to access the width this way, since you would be the one to define it. The size should ideally be a member in your class.

For example:

```
struct Player
{
    vec2 m_position;
    vec2 m_size;
    std::unique_ptr<b2Body> m_body;

    Player( const vec2 &pos_  = {0.f,0.f},
            const vec2 &size_ = {1.f,1.f} )
            : 
            m_position(pos_),
            m_size(size_),
            m_body(nullptr)
    {;}
};


// In your code...
std::unique_ptr<Player> m_player{ new Player({0.f,0.f},{3.f,2.f}) };  // make_unique if in C++14
b2World *m_world = new b2World(b2Vec2(0.f, -9.81f));  // use smart ptr here too..
b2BodyDef bodyDefinition;
b2PolygonShape bodyShape;
b2FixtureDef bodyFixture;

// PLAYER BODY DEFINITION
bodyDefinition.type = b2_dynamicBody;

// PLAYER SHAPE
bodyShape.SetAsBox(m_player->m_size.x, m_player->m_size.y);

// PLAYER FIXTURE
bodyFixture.shape = &bodyShape;

// PLAYER BIND TO THE WORLD
m_player->m_body.reset( m_world->CreateBody(&bodyDefinition) ); // or you can use the b2Body::CreateBody factory function. Then use b2Body::DestroyBody to delete the object.
m_player->m_body->SetActive(true);
m_player->m_body->CreateFixture(&bodyFixture);
```

From that point you can use your class members to access the position and size. That's the method I'd go for if I knew what each object (player) should be in the scene.

**2)** If you have a case however where you are not to define the size at initialisation, then you need to create an AABB around the the shape and from there, you can compute the size from the min and max points of the AABB. If the object rotates, then you need to compute the OBB.

For example:

```
m_player->m_body->SetTransform(m_player->m_position,0.f);
b2AABB aabb;
bodyShape.ComputeAABB(&aabb,m_player->m_body->GetTransform(),0);

Center = m_player->m_body->GetFixtureList()->GetAABB(0).GetCenter();
LowerBound = m_player->m_body->GetFixtureList()->GetAABB(0).lowerBound;
HigherBound = m_player->m_body->GetFixtureList()->GetAABB(0).lowerBound;
```

Then use this information to compute the width.

This information is found from the Box2d documentation (http://box2d.org/manual.pdf)

Comment: Wow thanks! But doesn't that also show that it would be more efficient to simply store a variable as the user data in order to achieve such information?

Comment: @asd What do you mean by "a variable as the user data"? If you mean a member variable of a class then yes, absolutely! The first method I showed you does exactly that, and this how you'd generally approach such a task if you know the kind of object you are going to create! The second method is used when you don't know (or cannot predict) what objects you'll end up creating, i.e. could be the result of a voronoi crack simulation. :-)

Comment: Great, I got it. I really like the idea of creating a "class" for the player and make a way of customize everything but couldn't you also just set the user data when initializing the bodydef?

Comment: @asd You could, but, the main reason of using classes/structures is to favour OOP. Furthermore, the b2BodyDef, b2PolygonShape and b2FixtureDef are only needed once to setup your body. At the end of the day, all the info from the b2BodyDef, b2PolygonShape and b2FixtureDef will be part of the b2Body and that's what you need to carry throughout your program. That's why I only included the b2Body in the Player structure. You can use the same b2BodyDef, b2PolygonShape and b2FixtureDef to initialise other objects other than the Player.

Comment: Perfect. But isn't this "User Data
User data is a void pointer. This gives you a hook to link your application objects to bodies. You should
be consistent to use the same object type for all body user data.
b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.userData = &myActor;" quicker than setting up a structure in order to save some specific information? I mean it is very simple to simply set the userData = &somedata instead of having to create a whole structure to save this information, however, of course there can be more advantages in the long run using structures/classes

Comment: @asd Tbh, I haven't used the userData method of the bodyDef. What's the type of "myActor" then? Assuming that you can do that, aren't you then constraining that bodyDef with only one object? What if you have many objects of the same type - you would have to create several bodyDefs (array), and then you'd have to find a way to access all the attributes of your objects. With a struct, you create only one bodyDef and attach all the information to the object's body pointer. It seems easier to me and more object oriented. But I guess it's up to you to decide what's best for your application.